# Reinstall MS Office after reinstalling Windows

Tags: microsoft-office, restore, reinstall, software-activation

I have reinstalled Windows 10 on a new hard drive as my laptop had become unusable. I still have the old hard drive with the old windows installation on it. Can I get MS Office back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you have/had a licensed copy of Windows and Office...)
Reinstall Windows (or recover to it). If you don't have the key, use the License Crawler tool I reference in the next paragraph. Reinstall Office next, and the same thing with your Office key.

If you still have your old data (specifically the registry), you may want to try [License Crawler by Martin Klinzmann](http://www.klinzmann.name/licensecrawler.htm). I've used it to recover several MS product keys, and there's [an option to target an old/removed hard drive's registry](http://www.klinzmann.name/licensecrawler_support.htm#USE_WINPE).

From the second link:

> 1. Start Linux or BartPE and save the following file: Windows\System32\Config\software (no extension)
> 2. Open Regedit: (WIN+R) enter regedit
> 3. In the Registry editor use "load hive..." to bind the file "software"
> 4. run the LicenseCrawler
> 5. Regedit "unload hive..."

As an added bonus, License Crawler is free for personal use. In terms of getting a Windows iso, this is the [official link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7). Hopefully your key is valid, as I recently did a software refresh for someone whose key had been flagged as invalid, and we were unable to restore the original (Win7) installation to that machine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Both Windows 10 and Office were genuine. They came with my Laptop when I purchased it. When I reinstalled Windows 10 it automatically activated (registered). I believe this is because Windows 10 stores the activation code in the laptop BIOS. Can I ask, what do you mean by start Linux? I have a Windows OS, not Linux. Also, are you saying the Office key will be in the registry on my old hard drive? Can you please clarify? Thanks!

Comment: If Office was installed on the laptop when you purchased it, the quickest way is to reinstall is to contact the OEM. I thought this was an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

No. you can't. as you told like new windows 10 on new hard drive and old windows on other hard drive. so you can't get MS office like it. you'll need MS office setup for install it with your new windows 10.
so you can spent MS office trial period with new windows 10 also you can use genuine MS office DVD for install it or you can buy and download from Micrsoft store now they offering MS Office 365 packages
http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/cat/categoryID.69403900

Thanks if you have any question you can comment again....